# How to store variable once program has terminated

Tags: java, variables, int

I have a counter that increments every time the user enters a specific word. How do I store the variables value once the program has terminated so that it can be used when the user launches the program again?

Comment: you could write that `variable` value in a file within `Runtime.addShutDownHook` method. And when you launch the Application you can read the value back from that file.

Comment: I would not rely on shutdown hooks since they cannot be called on reliably -> [If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Comment: @DeepakBala: So on which method You would rely most? Writing counter value to file each time counter is changed Which cause I/O overhead..? Or you have any other better option for that?

Comment: I doubt the overhead will be high given that a user manually enters each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the `int` to a `File` and then read the `File` when the program restarts.

You just need to check whether the file exists on startup, if it does read it otherwise set the `int` to zero (or whatever the default might be).

Here is a simple example using a `DataOutputStream` - some may say overkill but it allows your code to be extensible; you could write other stuff to the File too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int myCounter = 0;
    myCounter += 10;
    final File file = new File("/some/sensible/location");
    try (final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
        dos.writeInt(myCounter);
    }
    try (final DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
        System.out.println("Reading int from file: " + dis.readInt());
    }
}
```

Add a method called something like `updateFile` and make sure you keep the `File` in sync with the current program value.

Comment: Thanks @bmorris591 and all the others that replied. I was thinking of writing the number to a notepad, but thought Java would have had a better solution in place.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, you are going to want to use a `Scanner`, and read in the data that the user enters.  Then you are going to store what is entered into variables in the program, then write those out to a file.

[Here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) is a good tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a file (using Scanner for example) and then read from it whenever your program start.

Answer (score 1):

You can read / write from a properties file with a known path and reliable permissions. If this is a user preference / config you can use the [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API. The API can store the value across multiple platforms while abstracting where / how it stores it.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one simple value I would go with a simple file like the other answers.

If you need anything more I would go with a self contained database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). It's probably as fast to set up as to write your own simple file storage and you get way more out of it.